# How to calculate slope of linear regression for 1000 data.frames?

Tags: r, linear-regression

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20, 0,1), b=rnorm(20,1,2), c=rnorm(20, 2, 1), d=rnorm(20, 1,2))
 a          b          c           d
1  -0.114975143  2.8923335  2.9968141  1.68054858
2  -0.354557896 -2.3895332  3.7244438  1.99219906
3   0.271021912 -1.7725649  1.3278507  2.54157377
4  -1.981331306  2.7159506  3.4150731  3.57905491
5   0.003403129 -2.4912678  0.7665065  0.78206113
6  -0.843816087  0.4654837  2.2260497  5.16645779
7   0.091269485  2.6912003  2.1541783 -0.25013719
8  -0.221281275  1.6365565 -0.3745516  0.48183139
9   0.041891592 -1.1115767  1.2828104  0.07650962
10  1.182289018 -1.3741108  0.5180835  2.28457132
11 -0.498770473  1.3988605  1.3275124 -2.86340984
12 -0.277915549 -2.1960097  3.8331209  5.24206680
13 -0.522938649  0.9404911  3.0822281 -0.10335791
14  0.318142859  0.8651728  1.9794013  1.06888933
15 -0.870920037  3.9335164  4.5851187  0.37296019
16 -0.536834653 -0.2343890  1.5840454  0.83641016
17  1.369788371 -1.0971564  1.1922038 -0.91191447
18  0.355511037  1.1537255  1.2379696 -0.31673585
19  0.279638498  0.2543774  2.6568435  0.37737600
20  0.515248897 -4.3723985  2.5923414  2.60326350
```

I have 1000 data frames like this. I would like to apply linear regression (say for eg: y = column b, and x = column d) for each data frame separately to find out slopes. I would like to get a list of slopes and if possible regression equations for all 1000 models.

Comment: Is it on the same data you created in last post?  In that case, there won't be any difference in slope as the values doesn't change

Comment: @akrun In the original dataset, I have four columns (column 3 has 4 classes) and the changes we did only for column 2 and 4. When we developed 1000 data frames, values in each classes would be changing and hence, slopes will vary. Thanks so much for your kind attention and the much needed help.

Comment: It doesn't change because the rows are kept the same for 'b' and 'd'.  If it was the earlier one I suggested, it could vary because the values are interchanged

Comment: @akrun....rows are kept same for columns b and d. But the columns that I would be using for linear regressions are different. I did the analysis. I am really THANKFUL to you for your immediate help. It really saved a lot of time. HATS OFF to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the formula with `reformulate`, loop over the `list` of data.frames, create the model with `lm`, extract the slope from the coefficients (`coef`)

```
form1 <- reformulate('d', response = 'b')
sapply(lst1, function(x) coef(lm(form1, data = x))[[2]])
```

Comment: @akrun..lst1 in sapply(lst1, \(x) coef(lm(form1, data = x))[[2]]) is the object which contains all 1000 data.frames. Am I right?

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I assumed that you are storing the datasets in the `list` (`lst1` object name)

Comment: @akrun...I have a doubt. I am a beginner in R. In this code: 
sapply(lst1, function(x) coef(lm(form1, data = x))[[2]]), i placed the object 'lst1' in place of 'x' , and I got the answer. If I just leave 'x' as it is, even then I get the answer. Could you please clarify this. This doubt may be silly but I want to clarify it. Please...

Comment: @Rahul `function(x)` is a lambda function - i.e. it is a function created on the fly.  You can have `function(lst)` or `function(y)` which doesn't matter.  You could take the whole expression and create a new function i.e. `f1 <- function(y) coef(lm(form1, data = x))[[2]]` and then use `f1` i..e `sapply(lst1, f1)`

Comment: @akrun...Thanks a lot...for me to understand better, I will write it as function (name of the object).